# How do I disable legacy application from using XA datasources?

Tags: db2, ejb, websphere, mq, xa

I have this legacy application, that often fails importing data, probably because some transactions spanning too many sql statements. These long transactions are really not needed, so I'm trying to get rid of them and just use normal lookup and commits.
I'm not very familiar with XA datasources and don't really understand what controls if an XA or non XA is used. I have found places in the code that chooses between XA and non XA, but after setting this to always use non XA, I'm still getting the errors.
I have also un-checked the "Support two phase commit protocol" in "Queue connection factories" on my server, also without luck.
My server have datasources registered for both XA and non XA.
Any help on how and where to disable the use of XA datasources would be appreciated.

```
LocalTransact E   J2CA0030E: Method enlist caught com.ibm.ws.Transaction.IllegalResourceIn2PCTransactionException: Illegal attempt to enlist multiple 1PC XAResources
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredResources.enlistResource(RegisteredResources.java:871)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:1835)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerSet.enlistOnePhase(EmbeddableTranManagerSet.java:202)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.LocalTransactionWrapper.enlist(LocalTransactionWrapper.java:624)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.lazyEnlist(ConnectionManager.java:2697)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.lazyEnlist(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:2605)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.beginTransactionIfNecessary(WSJdbcConnection.java:743)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2792)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2745)
```

Answer (score 2):

Before answering this, I want to point out that changing transactional logic without full awareness of what you are doing can put your application at risk of data integrity issues, so proceed with caution.
If you look at the part of the stack that follows what you posted, it should show which application code is using the java.sql.Connection object.  Follow the code back to point where it obtains the Connection from a DataSource, and identify the JNDI name of the DataSource that it is using.  Switch your code to instead use the JNDI name of a ConnectionPoolDataSource (non-XA) rather than an XADataSource.  Once you do this, you might see errors about enlisting multiple one-phase resources in a transaction.  If so, your application was relying on two-phase commit which is only possible with XA and you will need to completely refactor it (if even possible at all) to avoid the use of two-phase commit. Alternately, if it was truly the intent that this data source should not be enlisting in JTA transactions, then you can mark it as transactional=false (if using Liberty) or nonTransactionalDataSource=true (WAS traditional) in which case it will avoid enlisting in JTA transactions and thus will not participate as a two-phase (XA) resource.

Comment: How or where do i set "nonTransactionalDataSource=true" ? I have both XA and non XA data sources. The XA have "Use this data source in container managed persistence (CMP) " checked and the non XA has it un-checked. I'm refactoring part of the application, but the rest still need those XA data sources. I think it's the EJB that determins if a XA data source is used, but how do I control that?

Comment: I think i found it. Data sources > myDataSource > WebSphere Application Server data source properties
 checked "Non-transactional data source"

Answer (score 0):

Before you make changes that you do not understand, you might be better advised to assess whether simply fixing or avoiding the (unspecified) errors may be less risky and less work that changing from XA to Non-XA behaviour.

At the very least for such a change from XA to non-XA you should engage a subject matter expert who can advise on the technical and business impacts of such a change specifically for the application involved.

You should edit your question to specify the exact errors (for example, sqlcodes or sqlstates) that the application receives in response to which kind of SQL actions.  Sometimes simple low risk configuration changes can resolve those errors.

Comment: I have already tried to see if I could solve the errors with simple fixes, but I have come to the conclusion, that the reason of the errors are very long transactions. Sometimes several hundreds statements executed in one transaction. This is bound to fail. So I have re-written a lot of code that now works fine in an integration test without using XA. I just needed to disable that the job uses one long transaktion when running on a server and I think I now found out, that it is controlled by an EJB that executes the job.

Comment: If you are certain that there is only a single RM in use (e.g. a single database) and no other RM in the XA , then the risk is small.  IF there is more than one RM involved, my advice would be to leave XA in place and either null-out the unwanted-transaction(s) that cause the errors, or address the errors. By nulling-out the unwanted transactions you will only impact a small part of the code, but removing the XA may compromise the integrity of the application.  For Db2 it is not a problem if a database-transaction has hundreds of SQL-statements, although that is poor programming.

Comment: The point is exactly, that it is poor programming by someone who choose to use all the bells and whistles he knew of for something that didn't need it at all. This is not a finacial or similar application where data integrity is crusial.